# PHP Artisan Tinker crashing from any command

Tags: php, laravel, tinker

I haven't had this problem before, but my `php artisan tinker` crashes from issuing any command - and leaves no logs whatsoever on what is causing the crash.

```
project4 $ php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.9.9 (PHP 7.3.0 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> use \App\Jobs\testJob;
project4 $
```

or even the simplest command:

```
project4 $ php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.9.9 (PHP 7.3.0 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> print("Hello World!");
project4 $
```

I almost wonder if it isn't connecting to PHP correctly, but I can't find any logs anywhere. Laravel has no trace of the commands. I ran `brew update`, but no difference. For the record, *all* of my projects are affected. I can't *tinker* on any of my projects. Help!

I did recently upgrade to PHP 7.3.0, which is working fine in every other area. Hmm...

Comment: Have you tried to run `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: Or blow away `vendor` entirely, then `composer install` to restore it.

Comment: @P.Ellul Tried it, didn't make any difference.

Comment: @ceejayoz Just tried... nothing.

Comment: For clarity, `artisan` is a tool which comes with Laravel, and is not related to `composer`.

Comment: Open your `artisan` file in your project root, it requires `/vendor/autoload.php`. These vendors are provided by `composer`.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

If you don't have the `pcntl` extension installed, try creating a config file at `~/.config/psysh/config.php` if not already there:

```
<?php
return [
  'usePcntl' => false,
];
```

Source: https://github.com/bobthecow/psysh/issues/540#issuecomment-446480753

Comment: Work fo me on a fresh Mojave install!

Comment: This was completely and utterly my issue. Just upgraded to php 7.3 on mojave. Thanks!

Comment: I've hit the same issue and the fix worked with a Ubuntu docker container and php 7.4.16. Possibly I have some php extension missing.

Answer (score 9):

This happens on Mojave when you upgrade/install PHP 7.3 using homebrew, 
*(It's a problem with PsySh (used by Tinker) and Homebrew's PHP 7.3.0 build.)*

Simple solution is, 
In your `php.ini` set

> pcre.jit=0

---

If you don't know which ini file is used, you can run `php --ini` to find it,

```
# /usr/local/etc/php/7.3/php.ini
- ;pcre.jit=1
+ pcre.jit=0
```