# Laravel Tinker immediately exits after first command

Tags: php, laravel, tinker

Whenever I type `php artisan tinker`, the shell comes up, but whenever I type in any commands and hit the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key, it immediately exits back to the command prompt. Why?

[image]

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure what's going on with this, it does it to one of my developers and we cannot figure out why

Comment: It's increasingly annoying

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53773098/php-artisan-tinker-crashing-from-any-command

Comment: I'm not installed via Homebrew though?

Comment: Then what is the expected behaviour?

Comment: The expected behaviour of that image would for it to echo back to me "lol". The problem is that whenever hitting the 'enter' key it does not allow me to actually execute the command

Comment: For all: Tinker should look act and feel like a PHP REPL that also incorporates laravel

Comment: @Ineedhelp, could you try this https://github.com/laravel/valet/issues/687#issuecomment-449671393 . In php.ini set ```pcre.jit=0```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If not already there, try creating a file at `~/.config/psysh/config.php` and add the following.

```
<?php

return [
  'usePcntl' => false,
];
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, kinda new to all this. Where is .config folder in my Laravel project?

Comment: THIS WORKED. THANK YOU